# I want to render a table in django using list as the column, but I'm getting the list repeating twice

Tags: html, django, templates, html-table

My list in teams has two object teams and my list in partidosjugados has a list of 2 items. However, when I use this code, the code renders a list below the column of PJ and the column of PG. Nevertheless, the code should only display below the column of PJ because the list from partidosjugados has only two elements and not four.

```
<table>

    <tr>
        <th> Equipo</th>
        <th>PJ</th>
        <th>PG</th>
        <th>PE</th>
        <th>PP</th>
        <th> GF </th>
        <th> GC </th>
        <th> GD </th>
        <th> PTS </th>
    </tr>
{% for team in teams %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{team.name}}</td>
    {% for partido in partidosjugados %}
        <td>{{partido}}</td>
    {% endfor %}

    </tr>
{% endfor %}

  <td></td>
   <td></td>
    <td></td>




</tr>




</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML elements are bit messed up. I am not sure if the cause of your problems or effect of you removing something from the template. In any case, if i look at this code, then the end result would be row ending but not starting and lot of table cells without row.

Also, your code shows that the table will be something like this

```
<tr><!-- Teams loop starts here -->
  <td> teamname </td>
  <td></td><!-- partidosjugados loop starts here -->
  ...
  <td></td><!-- partidosjugados loop ends here -->
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> teamname </td>
  <td></td><!-- partidosjugados loop starts here -->
  ...
  <td></td><!-- partidosjugados loop ends here -->
</tr><-- Teams loop ends here -->
```

From the table that you posted we see several problems.

1) You loop over partidosjugados once per every team. This seems to be the cause of your problems

2) Your post hints that the teams rows are not as long as header rows. In that case i suggest you use colspan attribute to make columns wider. Otherwise table will be ugly

3) your template shows last row ending but not starting.